# Propagating events in dijit.layout.BorderContainer

Tags: dojo

I've dijit BorderContainer overlaying a gfx surface which is movable (dojox.gfx.Moveable). Is there any way of disabling BorderContainer completely from catching mouse events and letting the Surface get them instead?
I've  been thinking of publishing the BorderContainer events to Surface, but that's seems like an overkill and might run into problems along the way.

Answer (score 0):

BorderContainer is just a DOM node with other nodes inside it, really.  Since they're not contained by the gfx surface, you'd probably have to wire the events up to relay them, the same as you would any other HTML element.  Perhaps you can use dojo.connect on the relevant events?